# installing php-devel on RHEL6 (PHP 5.3.3)

Tags: php, redhat, pecl, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying in vain to get the php oci_* extensions installed on our server, but i've hit a brick wall.

So far i've done this:

- Installed oracle basic & devel libraries (v10.2)
- Installed php-pear package

Now I'm trying to install oci8 using "pecl install oci8" but I get an error message about "phpize" command not being found.

My googling tells me that that is caused by "php-devel" not being installed, so i tried various different yum searches, e.g. "yum search php-devel", "yum search php5-devel", "yum search php-dev", etc... none of which could find anything.

I eventually found a repository hosted by "utterramblings" which had php-devel. So, now when I do a yum search using that repository, it can find "php-devel":

> php-devel.i386 : Files needed for building PHP extensions

But when I try to install it I get this:

> Error: Package: php-devel-5.2.17-jason.2.i386 (utterramblings)

```
       Requires: php = 5.2.17-jason.2
       Installed: php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.i686 (@rhel-i386-server-6)
           php = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
       Available: php-5.2.13-jason.1.i386 (utterramblings)
           php = 5.2.13-jason.1
       Available: php-5.2.14-jason.1.i386 (utterramblings)
           php = 5.2.14-jason.1
       Available: php-5.2.16-jason.1.i386 (utterramblings)
           php = 5.2.16-jason.1
       Available: php-5.2.17-jason.2.i386 (utterramblings)
           php = 5.2.17-jason.2
       Available: php-5.3.2-6.el6.i686 (rhel-i386-server-6)
           php = 5.3.2-6.el6
       Available: php-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.i686 (rhel-i386-server-6)
           php = 5.3.2-6.el6_0.1
       Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6.i686 (rhel-i386-server-6)
           php = 5.3.3-3.el6
       Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6_1.3.i686 (rhel-i386-server-6)
           php = 5.3.3-3.el6_1.3
       Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6_2.5.i686 (rhel-i386-server-6)
           php = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.5
       Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6_2.6.i686 (rhel-i386-server-6)
           php = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.6
       Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.i686 (rhel-i386-server-6)
           php = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.8
```

And to be honest, i'm not sure how to resolve that, presumably it has something to do with the version of php we have installed, but i'm not sure what I need to do to fix it.

These are our details:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago) [32bit]

PHP 5.3.3

Could anyone please advise me as to either:

a) what I need to do to resolve that issue and get php-devel installed from that repo

OR

b) point me in the direction of another repo which will allow me to easily install php-devel for our server

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed to get it installed eventually.

To quickly detail what I did for any future viewers, I ran:

```
yum list installed
```

To find out what exact package of php we had installed (5.5.3-14.el6_3 I think or something like that).

Then searched for the relevant php-devel package to match that php package version on rpm.pbone.net.

Tried to install that and failed with a "failed depencies" error "automake needed to install php-devel".

Ran:

```
yum install automake
```

Then tried to installed the package again:

```
rpm -Uvh URLOFPACKAGE
```

It installed correctly, then ran:

```
pecl install oci8
```

And followed the instructions.

Restarted httpd service and done.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, friend! I can't believe how hard it is to get php-devel working... I can't believe php-devel isn't listed as a php-pear dependency!